# Couldn't register WMI __EventConsumer in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

My PC environment is Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation, Build 17763.rs5_release.180914-1434

When I entered this command `$consumer = ([wmiclass]"\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer").CreateInstance()` in `Powershell` (Run as Administrator), I got an exception like below.

```
 Cannot convert value "\\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer" to type "System.Management.ManagementClass". Error: "Not found
 "
 At line:1 char:1
 + $consumer = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsume ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToWMIClass
```

I tried to digger more deeper information, then I got some messages like below

```
 System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot convert value "\\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer" to type "System.Management.ManagementClass". Error: "Not found " ---> System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert value "\\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer" to type "System.Management.ManagementClass". Error: "Not found " ---> System.Management.ManagementException: Not found 
    at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
    at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
    at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_wbemObject()
    at System.Management.PropertyData.RefreshPropertyInfo()
    at System.Management.PropertyDataCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
    at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertToWMIClass(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recursion, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertToWMIClass(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recursion, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

Actually, I could register __EventFilter, __EventConsumer and __FilterToConsumerBinding at first.
However, after trying some commands related to register and unregister WMI (Sorry I didn't remember what commands I tried...), I couldn't register `__EventConsumer` anymore, even though I tried to reboot PC and unregister all of them, I still get the exception like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this instead to create a new instance in the CommandLineEventConsumer Class.  The same will go for Filters and Consumer Binding.

```
$Properties = @{
    "Name"="Test"
    "CommandLineTemplate"="C:\Windows\Notepad.exe"
}

New-CimInstance -Namespace 'ROOT\subscription' -ClassName 'CommandLineEventConsumer' -Arguments $Properties
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. After I tried your command, I got this exception 
`New-CimInstance : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ New-CimInstance -Namespace 'ROOT\subscription' -ClassName 'CommandLin ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (CommandLineEventConsumer:CimInstance) [New-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.NewCimInstanceCommand`
But I could register on other PC with same environment successfully.

Comment: yikes, sounds like you have a corrupt wmi repository.  Something probably deleted that class.  Follow the instructions here https://superuser.com/questions/190960/repair-wmi-on-windows-7  (The answer that starts with "To fully rebuild the WMI Repository follow these steps:") and you should be in good shape again.

Comment: After repairing WMI, I could register Consumer by using your method. However, I still encountered exception by using my method but with **different error message**.
`Cannot convert value "\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer" to type "System.Management.ManagementClass".
Error: "Invalid parameter "`
I have tried these three repairing method [https://superuser.com/a/995926](https://superuser.com/a/995926), [https://superuser.com/a/1431461](https://superuser.com/a/1431461) and [https://superuser.com/a/274651](https://superuser.com/a/274651)

Comment: Good, looks like from that error message you no longer have an issue with WMI. That error makes sense with your original syntax, PowerShell is interpreting your command as casting a string to a ManagementClass. Its highly encouraged that you use the built in New-CIMInstance cmdlets for creating WMI Instances. If you are using the .NET syntax as part of log evasion for a red team exercise then the proper syntax for that would be... `[wmiclass]::new("root\subscription:SMTPEventConsumer").CreateInstance()`

Comment: Keep in mind you will still need to fill in properties and use the .put() command to commit the new instance.  Since this answer seems to have helped can you please upvote and mark as answered.  Thanks

Comment: Although I couldn't use the original way to register WMI. But your answer could work well and advice help me a lot. Thanks again @Paul

Comment: I made a typo in my code up there... sorry, it was late where I am :).  I meant to put 

`[wmiclass]::new("root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer").CreateInstance()`

Comment: `[wmiclass]::new("root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer").CreateInstance()` works well now. Thanks for your help.